# What's the mechanism for this isotopic substitution reaction?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I'm curious to know what's the mechanism of:
$$\ce{HF + D^+ \rightarrow DF + H^+}$$

Comment: Maybe you should include your own thoughts on this?

Comment: @tschoppi. I have an idea (probably stupid) but I would prefer not to contaminate the discussion with it.

Comment: Well, you got my answer. I'd be curious to hear about your approach.

Comment: The use of a double arrow is appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this question you should understand the [kinetic isotope effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_isotope_effect).

Since you deliver no real data about reaction rate constants I assume that the dissociation of $\ce{HF}$ is faster (has a larger $k_\text{dis}$) than the dissociation of $\ce{DF}$. I postulate the following mechanism:

$\ce{HF + D+ <=>[k_\text{dis}^\ce{HF}] H+ + F- + D+ <=>[][k_{\text{dis}}^\ce{DF}] DF + H+}$

Essentially it is a pretty simple reaction mechanism, but it tends to forming $\ce{DF}$ over $\ce{HF}$ because the deuterium dissociates more slowly.

Comment: I was thinking about an intermediate (HFD)+ based on some quantum mechanical calculations I performed.

Comment: Hm, given the high strength of the HF bond that is also entirely possible. Depending on the medium, of course.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici That is probably a good description for a gas phase reaction. However, when inspecting the reaction in a condensed phase, calculations must be done much more carefully as bare hydrogen nuclei are extremely polarizing and will drag along one or more solvating entities with them.

Comment: Actually, $\ce{F-}$ isn't that stable, and one would expect a concerted mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You know this happens in water all the time...what do you mean by mechanism? this is just proton jumping or hopping. The kinetics are are a side issue.